# Normality in a tower of cyclic extensions of global fields, as in Artin-Tate

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, class-field-theory

Let $L_0$ be a global field without real places, that is, a global function field or a totally imaginary number field,
and let $V_f(L_0)$ denote the set of finite (that is, non-archimedean) places of $L_0$.

Let $n>1$ be a natural number.
For a given finite set $S_0\subset V_f(L_0)$, we construct a cyclic extension $L_1/L_0$ of degree $n$
such that
$$(L_0)_{v_0}\otimes_{L_0} L_1 \text{ is a $field$ for all places  $v_0\in S_0\subset V_f(L_0)$}.$$
Here $(L_0)_{v_0}$ denotes the completion of the field $L_0$ at the place $v_0$.
This construction is possible by Theorem X.6 (which I use as a black box) in the book "Class Field Theory" by Artin and Tate.
Moreover, this construction is not unique: we make choices.

Let $r>1$ be a natural number.
We choose a finite set $S_1\subset V_f(L_1)$ according to a certain rule, and construct a cyclic extension $L_r/L_1$ of degree $n^{r-1}$
such that
$$(L_1)_{v_1}\otimes_{L_1} L_r\ \text{ is a $field$ for all places  $v_1\in S_1\subset V_f(L_1)$}.$$
Again, we use Theorem X.6 of Artin-Tate, and again our construction is not unique: we make choices.

Then the extensions $L_r/L_1$ and $L_1/L_0$ are cyclic, hence normal, but the extension $L_r/L_0$ might not be normal.

> **Question 1.** Can we make good choices when constructing the cyclic extensions $L_1/L_0$ and $L_r/L_1$
> so that the extension $L_r/L_0$ will be normal?

Now let $\sigma$ be a generator of the Galois group ${\rm Gal}(L_r/L_1)$.
Then the fixed subfield in $L_r$ of $\sigma^{n^0}$ is $L_1$,
and the fixed subfield in $L_r$ of $\sigma^{n^{r-1}}$ is $L_r$.
For $1\le s\le r$ we *define* $L_s$ to be the fixed subfield in $L_r$ of $\sigma^{n^{s-1}}$;
then the new definition of $L_1$ and $L_r$ coincides with the old one.

The extension $L_s/L_1$ is a cyclic extension of degree $n^{s-1}$, hence normal,
and the extension $L_1/L_0$ is normal too.

> **Question 2.**  Can we make good choices when constructing the cyclic extensions $L_1/L_0$ and $L_r/L_1$
> so that the extensions $L_s/L_0$ will be normal for all $s$?